# Невыносимо тормозит firefox на ubuntu,vps сервер

Tags: linux

После запуска через комманду firefox, открывается минуту и я уже молчу про открытие страниц, один символ вводится секунд 10.
При запуске firefox'а вот такие ошибки:
(firefox:28037): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:28037): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:28037): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:28037): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

Comment: Каковы характеристики VPS и какая система виртуализации?

Comment: Процессор 1, Оперативная память 1 гб, HDD 30gb. Видеокарта SVGA II.

Comment: Частота процессора какая? Память-то кем-либо помимо фаерфокса не забита?

Comment: Система виртуализации VMware. Памяти до запуска firefox свободно 80 процентов.

Comment: Процессор 2.2 GHz.

Comment: accountsservice какой версии ?

Comment: Можно нескромный вопрос? Нахрена запускать фокс на сервере?

Comment: Чтобы скачать прокси-снифер.

Comment: А кто-нибудь разницу замечал в скорости работы браузеров Google chrome и firefox на ubunt'е.

Comment: Это вопрос?????